# populate a drop down of states from a country list - angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

Below is my snippet from java spring controller to return a list of states

Here is the sample json result from postman to fetch states in respect to country id.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "state1",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "state2",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "state3",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "state4",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "state5",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    }
]
```

I am consuming the endpoint in angular as shown to fetch state list.

```
                var myJSON = res.data;
                var states = [];
                angular.forEach(myJSON, function (item)
                        {
                    states.push(item);
                        });
                alert("500 "+ states);
```

The state list is never shown and the dropdown of the states never gets populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful of what you are referencing into your template.

First, your **ctrl.states** (template ref) is not the same object of **states** (controller ref).

Decide if you want to use *Controller instance* or *$scope instance* to bind your ref.

---

Working with **$scope**, your controller will be:

```
$scope.states = [] ;

angular.forEach(myJSON, function (item) {
    $scope.states.push(item);
});
```

And the template:

```
<label>State</label>
<select ng-model="state" name="state" required >

    <option ng-repeat="s in states" value="{{s.name}}">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I moved the **ngRepeat** to the option tag because you don't need to iterate compile more than one select, instead you need to add an option for each element of your *states* object.

Remove too those classes because is the Angular engine that will add these when an ngModel is detected on the *element*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for putting an answer but the state dropdown is never shown. So I dont even know if the states.push is working solution

Comment: I think you are not referring to the right object into template, i'm updating the answer

Comment: the state dropdown is empty

Comment: Have you properly connected controller with the html? Can you post this part of code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your array reference and of course as previous as you have to push items into an array.

try below code it will works

Note: Don't run code in snippet it won't run bcoz angular lib and links are not added to it

```js
var myJSON = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "state1",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "state2",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "state3",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "state4",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "state5",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MyCountry"
        }
    }
];


$scope.states = [];
angular.forEach(myJSON, function(item) {
  $scope.states.push(item);
});

alert($scope.states); //alertsthe values
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<label>State</label>
<select ng-repeat="s in states" ng-model="state" formcontrol name="state" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" required>
  <option value="{{s.name}}">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```